# What does 'FETCH_HEAD' mean in the configuration of a Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAKP9.png)

If I push a Jenkins file to Gerrit so my code changes are under review, can I test my changes by setting the branch as 'FETCH_HEAD'? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

No, `FETCH_HEAD` cannot be used here.

For Gerrit changes under review, or pending changes, they have a specific group of branches or refs, named as `refs/changes/a/b/c`, to point at all patch-sets. `b` is the unique auto-increment number for each change. `a` is the result of `b % 100`. `c` is the ordinal of each patch-set.

Taking a change `http://gerrithost/gerrit/c/12345` for example, the change number is `12345`. The branch of its 4th patch-set is `refs/changes/45/12345/4`. You can use `git fetch origin refs/changes/45/12345/4 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD` to retrieve and checkout the commit.

After you fetch or pull a ref, the ref's tip object (a commit in most cases) sha1 is stored in `FETCH_HEAD`. For example,

```
git fetch origin master
git log -1 FETCH_HEAD
```

You will see `FETCH_HEAD` is the last commit of `master` in the remote repository.

```
git fetch origin dev
git log -1 FETCH_HEAD
```

Now `FETCH_HEAD` has become the last commit of `dev`. With `FETCH_HEAD`, you don't have to consider what name the fetched ref has.

For Gerrit changes, I would recommend the plugin `Gerrit Trigger`. It's very easy to configure and use.